# Capture changes on object in expressions

Tags: r

**Is there any way to capture all operations performed on the object?**
I would like to append new column to `iris` and have code saved somewhere which will generate me the appended version.

```
> iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa

> iris2 = iris
> iris2$IsSetosa = ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", 1, 0)
> iris2$IsSetosa 
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [75] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[112] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
[149] 0 0
> head(iris2)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species IsSetosa
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa        1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa        1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa        1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa        1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa        1
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa        1
```

**I am looking for a way to capture and store `ifelse(iris$Species == "setosa", 1, 0)` expression.** So i can easily replicate the `iris2`. In other words, I am looking for something like version control for objects, but in automatic way. Thus, each change performed on the object should be logged and can be replicated.

*In order to keep the issue simple, I do not expect any changes dependent on external objects. This implies that all changes are based on the own data and/or some supplied constants.*

There is package `track` which does changes detection and persist them to disk. I am looking for `code-generator` of such changes.

`dplyr` use lazy evaluations on `tbl` object, which I assume stores all expression to be converted to SQL calls if needed.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can't you just create a function? Also, usually you would write a script, which is your "log".

Comment: I don't understand it, either. Isn't that "logging" inherent in R-scripting in contrast to for example doing analyses in Excel?

Comment: Agree, scripting is already "logging". But if I do some sequence of calls from different functions/files, I just would like to aggregate all changes on the object automatically, instead of manual aggregation.